# iOS - UIImageView slight glitch

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uiview, uiimageview

I have a myriad of `UIImageViews` that act as 'tiles' on a map.  They align up next to one another to form a grid of images.

Ordinarily, the grid images are flush against each other, but whenever the iPhone or iPad device is rotated, or if a `UIView` is applied to the view that contains these tiles, the spaces between the `UIImageViews` become momentarily visible, showing off the grid pattern that I'd like to be invisible.

Any ideas what might be causing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider using [CATiledLayer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CATiledLayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html) to draw all the images in a single view instead of using multiple subviews. There's a nice writeup on using it at [Cocoa Is My Girlfriend](http://www.cimgf.com/2011/03/01/subduing-catiledlayer/). CATiledLayer makes it easy to build an image out of smaller tiles, display higher resolution images as the user zooms in, and avoid memory problems that come from keeping too much of a large image loaded.

Answer (score 3):

this is happening because you are using different views (here `uiimageview`). Since they are not part of the same fabric during any animation or change in view hierarchy there is a chance that the gap between them would be visible.

This is a very common problem in graphics programming. The way to fix this problem is to have one single view and add these `uiimageviews` as sub-layers to this view. That way all the imageviews are part of the same fabric and the gap would not be visible.

I did not post any code but then so did you ;)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. At the moment, all of the `UIImageViews` are subviews within a single `UIView`. If I animate this `UIView` I get the same problem as in my original post. I assume there is no way to fix this?

Comment: dont make it subviews! you need to add them as part of the main view's CALayer. or CATiledLayer is another option as mentioned already.